# How to prove $xy>x+y$ if $x,y \in (2,\infty)\subseteq \Bbb R$

Tags: proof-explanation

I am new to proofs. This is my first proof-based mathematics class, and it is a hard transition from my high school classes. I am a second semester freshman.

My original question was:

> Prove that there is a real number with the property that for any two
>   larger numbers, there is another real number that is larger than the
>   sum of the two numbers and less than their product.

I have attempted this by a constructive proof (which is possible according to my distinguished professor) and am very unwilling to attempt a nonconstructive proof until I have proven it by a constructive proof. I said:

"Let $x,y,z,$ and $t \in \Bbb R$, with $y>x$ and $z>x$. Because $x,y,z,$ and $t$ are real numbers, if we choose a pair of $y$ and $z$ such that $yz>(y+z)$ , the following always holds $\exists t(yz>t>(y+z))$. Let $x=2$ and let $\epsilon$ be some arbitrary infinitesimal positive quantity. The smallest product of $y$ and $z$ would then be the product of $y=2+\epsilon$ and $z=2+\epsilon$ and the product would be $yz=4+2\epsilon + \epsilon^2$. Similarly, the smallest sum of $y$ and $z$ would be the sum if $y=2+\epsilon$ and $z=2+\epsilon$ which is $(y+z)=4+2\epsilon$. We see that $yz>(y+z)$ which is equivalent to $4+2\epsilon + \epsilon^2 > 4+2\epsilon$..."

And this is where I get stuck. I don't think I am near the end of the proof, I feel like I need a lemma to complete this. I want the lemma to be the proof of:

> Prove that for any pairs of real numbers $x$ and $y$, where $x>2$ and
>   $y>2$, the following always holds: $xy>(x+y)$

I thought of proving this lemma by approaching using the AM-GM inequality which I learned in competitive mathematics during high school, since one side is a product and one side is a summation, but I have not started it. I feel like I am being a little redundant in the proof, going in circles, or writing without much thinking.

Disregarding the original question (although I appreciate hints), how would I approach the proof of the lemma?

Comment: Write $xy - x - y = x(\tfrac12 y - 1) + y (\tfrac12 x - 1)$ and see what you can do with this.

Comment: Your edit has not improved the situation! You should just have removed the reference to $z$ in the original title.

Comment: I updated it a couple of times. Please tell me if there is something wrong in my title.

Comment: It's fixed now. You want the title to be correct and inviting to readers at the same time.

Comment: Thank you. I guess mathematicians like it concise.

Comment: I think @HansEngler's edit $x,y \in (2,\infty)\subseteq \Bbb R$ is unnecessarily formal. Just write "if $x,y>2$".

Answer (score 3):

The inequality is equivalent to
$$(x-1)(y-1)>1 $$
which clearly holds for $x,y>2$. Then, if you take $t=\frac{xy+x+y}{2}$, you will have $x+y<t<xy$.

Comment: My mind is so closed to being blown away. When I saw @Hans Engler posted $xy-x-y$ I was like OH I CAN APPLY SFFT from competitive mathematics. So I did $xy-x-y=x(y-1)-y$, then I add one to both sides so $xy-x-y+1=x(y-1)-y+1$ which is equivalent to $xy-x-y+1=(x-1)(y-1)$. The only confusion is how did you get from here to the inequality you posted?

Comment: @KennethDang Which one are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

If $x>z$ and $y > z$ then $a=x-z> 0$ and $b=y-z>0$.

And $x+y = (z+a) + (z+b) = 2z +(a+b)$.  And $xy = (z+a)(z+b) = z^2 + (a+b)z + ab$.

We want to find a $z$ so that $2z + (a+b) < z^2 +(a+b)z + ab$ for all possible positive $ab$.

This will happen if and only if $0 < (z^2-2z) + (a+b)(z-1) + ab=z(z-2) + (a+b)(z-1) + ab$ for all positive $a,b$

We know that $ab > 0$ and $(a+b)>0$ for all positive $a,b$ so if we can have $z(z-2)\ge 0$ and $z-1\ge 0$ that will be good enough.

If $z = 2$ and $x>2$ and $y > 2$ and $a= x-2>0;b=y-2>0$ then $xy=(2+a)(2+b) = 4+2(a+b)+ab> 4+a+b = x+y$.

So $z=2$ is just such a number.

And if $x+y < xy$ then $w=\frac {(x+y) + xy}2$ will be that $x+y < w < xy$ and $w$ is such a number as we need.

Note:  We haven't proven that $z=2$ is the *least* such possible value but we weren't *asked* to prove that.

But we can prove that.

If $z < 2$ we just have to prove there exist *any* $x,y> z$ where this fails.

If $x = y = 1$ then $x+y = 2 >1=xy$ so this will fail if $z< 1$.  ANd if $1\le z< 2$ then if we let $x+y = \frac {z+2}2$.  Then $x+y = z+ 2$ while $xy= \frac{z^2 + 4z + 4}{4} = \frac {z^2}4 + z + 1= z + (\frac {z^2}4 +1)$.  But $1\le x < 2$ so $z+(\frac {z^2}4 +1) < z + (1+1)=z+2 =x+y$.  So that is a counter example.

So $z$ is the smallest such number.  (Similar for any $z > 2$ this will hold.  After all, if $x,y > z > 2$ then $x,y > 2$ and we know that in that case $x+y < xy$.)

Answer (score 0):

$$y(x-1)> x\iff y> {x\over x-1} =1+{1\over x-1}$$

Since ${1\over x-1}$ is decreasing for $x\geq 2$ it has maximum value at $x=2$, so for $x>2$ it is less than $1$ and thus $y>2$.